# No results printed from readfile() function in php

Tags: php

I made a download function in my code that looks like this, as what I had learned from some websites on how to download files. The files are in zip file type.

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($link).'"');
$result = readfile($link);

//print $result
print_r($result);exit;
```

I know there are some things missing in the header part but let's leave it to that. My question here is whenever I print the `$result`, I got no messages. It just downloaded the files without printing the `readfile` function response. I like to get the response so that I will know if the file download has completed. Does anyone knows why it's not showing the response?

Updated: I used this in a form of script, so no options are shown in the page to click and download the link. When I visit the URL, it will automatically download the link I statically provided in the code.

Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: It doesn't work this way. You either show a page or download a file, doing both at the same time is __impossible__

Comment: but how should I do that?

Comment: @G.Curs I suggest you to use download page and then call download via AJAX

Comment: What does it mean - download completed? User can press `cancel` when agree to download, what is then?

Comment: @u_mulder, there's no user interaction with this. I just like to check if the download completes.

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://php.net/readfile):

> Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.
>
> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the number of bytes read from the file. If an error occurs,
>   `FALSE` is returned and unless the function was called as @readfile(),
>   an error message is printed.

You have a binary file:

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
```

If you inject the number of bytes returned by the function in the middle of the ZIP file, you'll just corrupt it.

I'll illustrate it with a small 148-byte ZIP:

```
<?php
$link = __DIR__ . '/foo.zip';
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($link).'"');
$result = readfile($link);
print_r($result);
exit;
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Binary dump]

As you can see, the output gets appended to the actual ZIP contents. Most archivers are smart enough to discard the invalid bytes and expand the ZIP file successfully but it's wrong nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro, but the returned values are not printed. Why is that so?

Comment: Well, we only have your word that you're printing it, you haven't shown how. But it can be tricky to find stuff in binary files. Are you using an hexadecimal editor, such as [https://hexed.it/](https://hexed.it/)?

Comment: I printed it this way: ```print_r($result)```, I also updated my question. I don't have any idea about the editor you've been referring too.

Comment: @G.Curs I've extended my answer, I hope it's clearer now.